# Update sender metadata from receiver app

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I have a Sender (android) app (using v3 library) that sends customData to a custom Receiver app. One of the customData that's passed is an array of objects:

`[{
  season: 1,
  episode: 1,
  title: "Pilot",
  streamUrl: "http://streams.com/s1e1.mp4"
},{
  season: 1,
  episode: 2,
  title: "Second episode",
  streamUrl: "http://streams.com/s1e2.mp4"
},{
  season: 1,
  episode: 3,
  title: "Third episode",
  streamUrl: "http://streams.com/s1e3.mp4"
}]`

and the custom Receiver app has an autoplay logic that plays the next episode when the current one is nearing the end. This works perfectly fine, no issues here.

When the first episode plays, the title 'Pilot' shows in the mini and fullscreen player controls in the Sender app. However, when the Receiver app plays the "Second episode", the Sender app player controls still shows "Pilot" as the title.

Would it be possible to update the Sender app's data from the Receiver? Can you please share the code on how to do it?

I've gone thru the Receiver API docs, used most of the methods such as **MediaManager setMediaInformation()**
`https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.MediaManager#setMediaInformation`

but to no avail. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong or additional code needs to be written in the Sender app as well? Or maybe it's just not possible?

Appreciate all your inputs. Thanks for your answers in advance!

Update:

From sender(Android) side, both MiniControllerFragment and ExpandedControllerActivity use MetaData to show like title and subtitle.
It seems the only way to update MetaData is [load()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/media/RemoteMediaClient#load(com.google.android.gms.cast.MediaInfo)). However, when it comes to autoplay, Chromecast will play next episode automatically. It's impossible to call load() again. We couldn't find a way to update MetaData as described above.

Comment: Not 100% sure if this is what you're looking for but there is a note in [Media messages](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver#media-messages) that states that you can pass information to the receiver using the [LoadRequestData.customData field](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.MediaManager.LoadRequestData#customData), through the API's load method (in Chrome, the [Session.loadMedia](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/chrome.cast.Session#loadMedia) function).